# Empty *args - what does python do here?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just got hit by the following problem:

I have a method that looks somwhat like the following:

```
def funfun(fun,args):
    fun(*args)
```

Now when the passed fun takes no arguments and args being an empty list, python will complain that I passed fun an argument. Why is that? What is getting passed in that case?

(In my real code, fun is called fun(obj,*args) but really takes just one argument, the concept should be the same)

[Edit]

This is the complete code:

```
def invoke(self, object_self, method, proceed, args):
    proxy_method = getattr(self.proxy, method.getName(), self.placeholder)
    if proxy_method == self.placeholder:
        return proceed.invoke(object_self,args)
    else:
        return proxy_method(object_self,*args)
```

Comment: Post an example that demonstrates the error, and the actual error message. What you say should not happen, so you must be doing something wrong in the code you haven't shown here.

Comment: Are you sure? When I call a no-args function with `*empty` (`empty==[]`) it works just fine...

Comment: :-/ Ok I see my mistake now. I used a bound instance function and thought it was the unbound class function. My example doesn't show that mistake at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake here is that I mistakenly thought that proxy_method is unbound and needs to be given the object to be called on as argument. Apart from the fact that object_self is the wrong object, the result from getattr is actually a bound method, bound to the proxy instance and thus does not need to be passed the proxy object. The correct code is:

```
def invoke(self, object_self, method, proceed, args):
    proxy_method = getattr(self.proxy, method.getName(), self.placeholder)
    if proxy_method == self.placeholder:
        return proceed.invoke(object_self,args)
    else:
        return proxy_method(*args)
```